# Cloud Firestore not updating correctly when record is added in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I am developing a Flutter app and I am using the `cloud_firestore` plugin. I have a collection of submissions and I am using the `StreamBuilder` to display them (which I am assuming will update when the stream changes). I literally took the example from the plugin examples as there is not much documentation on how to do things using the plugin. When I added a record, the list of documents that I am displaying gets longer, but it seems to be copying one of the submissions instead of inserting the new submission. The new submission does not show after it is added. Here is the code for how I am displaying the list:

```
// At the top of the class home.dart. 
final submissions = Firestore.instance.collection('submissions');

// This is in submission-list.dart and the above submissions 
// is passed in to the contructor
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: submissions
          .where('owner_uid', isEqualTo: this.user.uid)
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .snapshots,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            var date = _formatDate(document['timestamp']);
            String body = _constructCardBody(document['weight'],
                bodyFat: document['bodyFat']);
            String id = document.documentID;
            return new SubmissionCard(id: id, title: date, body: body, submissions: submissions);
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Here is submission-card.dart in full:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../utils/logger.dart';
import './block-button.dart';

class SubmissionCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String body;
  final CollectionReference submissions;

  SubmissionCard({this.id, this.title, this.body, this.submissions});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>
      new _SubmissionCardState(id: this.id, title: this.title, body: this.body, submissions: this.submissions);
}

class _SubmissionCardState extends State<SubmissionCard> {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String body;
  bool showActionButtons = false;
  final CollectionReference submissions;

  _SubmissionCardState({this.id, this.title, this.body, this.submissions});

  void _showEditScreen() {}

  void _showActionButtons() {
    setState(() {
      showActionButtons = true;
    });
  }

  void _hideActionButtons() {
    setState(() {
      showActionButtons = false;
    });
  }

  Future<Null> _deleteSubmission() async {
    try {
      await submissions.document(id).delete();
      await Logger.log('error', 'stackTrace');
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      await Logger.log(error, stackTrace);
    }
  }

  void _closeDialog() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    _hideActionButtons();
  }

  Future<Null> _warnAboutDeletion() async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new SimpleDialog(
          title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
          children: <Widget>[
            new SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                this._deleteSubmission();
                this._closeDialog();
              },
              child: new Text("I'm sure. Delete it."),
            ),
            new SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: _closeDialog,
              child: new Text("Nope. Take me back."),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: _showActionButtons,
      onTap: _hideActionButtons,
      child: new Card(
        elevation: showActionButtons ? 8.0 : 2.0,
        key: new GlobalKey(),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              trailing: showActionButtons
                  ? new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new IconButton(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                          onPressed: _showEditScreen,
                          color: Colors.black12,
                          splashColor: Colors.black26,
                          highlightColor: Colors.black12,
                        ),
                        new IconButton(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onPressed: _warnAboutDeletion,
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                          splashColor: Colors.black26,
                          highlightColor: Colors.black12,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : new Container(),
              isThreeLine: true,
              title: new Text(title),
              subtitle: new Text(
                body,
                style: new TextStyle(height: 3.0),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Link to repo: https://github.com/dericgw/bodwatch

Before, when I have worked with Firebase, this collection would automatically update. I have never seen this weird behavior before. Now, I am new to Flutter and Dart, so I could be missing something for sure.

Comment: what's `_submissions` ? Is it the same as the `submissions` in home.dart?

Comment: Also can you describe this "the list of documents that I am displaying gets longer, but it seems to be copying one of the submissions instead of inserting the new submission. The new submission does not show after it is added." more precisely?

Comment: @Pacane Yes, `_submissions` is the same as `submissions`. To clarify, what I said - If the list has 3 items and I add an item, the list then has 4 items. However, the item that is added to the list is not the one that was submitted. One of the original 3 items is duplicated. Make sense?

Comment: It's hard to see what's really going on without the full code. Can you post the code of SubmissionCard? 

Also, are you sure it's not adding the new item, but you just don't display the items properly? Because the first snapshot of the stream should be all records, and the subsequent snapshots will be just the changes.

Comment: It is possible that I am not displaying them correctly, as I am new to Flutter (and Dart). In the past with Firebase, (using JS) when the snapshot changed, things would update automatically. I would not have to do anything to manually update it. I have updated the answer to show the submission card code and a link to the repo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the indexing in firebase console.

In your case, you need to a multiple indexes.
1. owner_uid, ascending
2. timestamp, descending

And the problem should solve.