# Firebase sub collection data updating is not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update data on the firebase subcollection, but it's not working, but the reading and deleting is working properly. here is the code.

### Reading Data

```
  @override
  Stream<List<EpisodesModel>> readEpisode({
    required id,
  }) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('courses')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('eps')
        .orderBy('episodeNum', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((doc) => EpisodesModel.fromJson(doc.data()))
            .toList());
  }
```

this is how I'm reading the data from the firebase sub-collection.
I'm using the same way to update the data.

here is the code of updating

### Updating Data

```
  @override
  Future update({
    required courseIDforEpsUpdate,
    required id,
    required caption,
    required time,
    episodeNum,
    link,
    head,
  }) async {
    final docCourse = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses');
    final docEps =
        docCourse.doc(courseIDforEpsUpdate).collection('eps').doc(id);

    log('crs id : $courseIDforEpsUpdate');
    log('eps id : $id');

    docEps.update({
      'caption': caption,
      'time': time,
      'episodeNum': episodeNum,
      'link': link,
    });
  }
```

and when I press update nothing happens. please comment if I miss any code that you need to check the problem.

here is how I did normal collection update

```
 @override
  Future update({
    required courseIDforEpsUpdate,
    required id,
    required caption,
    required time,
    head,
    episodeNum,
    link,
  }) async {
    final docCourse = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses').doc(id);
    docCourse.update({
      'caption': caption,
      'time': time,
      'head': head,
    });
  }
```

here is the DB image

[image]

### EDIT

here is the update button code

```
  onTap: () async {
        await editEpisodePop(
          courseID: courseID,
          type: ActionType.edit,
          caption: data!.caption,
          episodeNum: data!.episodeNum.toString(),
          id: data!.id,
          link: data!.link,
          time: data!.time,
          context: context,
          episodeID: data!.id,
        );
      },
```

here is the popup widget code

```
Future<void> editEpisodePop({
  required BuildContext context,
  required type,
  required caption,
  required episodeNum,
  id,
  required courseID,
  required link,
  required time,
  required episodeID
}) async {
  //creating a dialog box , the popup screen code

  final captionController = TextEditingController();
  final episodeNumController = TextEditingController();
  final linkController = TextEditingController();
  final timeController = TextEditingController();
  final idShow = TextEditingController();
  final _eps = FirebaseEpisodeFacade();

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (ctx) {
      if (type == ActionType.edit) {
        if (id == null) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }

        captionController.text = caption ?? ' ';
        linkController.text = link ?? ' ';
        timeController.text = time ?? ' ';
        episodeNumController.text = episodeNum ?? ' ';
        idShow.text = episodeID;
      }

      return SimpleDialog(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 69, 73),
        // backgroundColor: mainTheme,
        title: const Text('Add Users', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        children: [
          //code of textfield
          _TextFieldWidget(
            hintText: 'Caption',
            controller: captionController,
          ),
          _TextFieldWidget(
            hintText: 'Episode link',
            controller: linkController,
          ),
          _TextFieldWidget(
            hintText: 'Episode Time',
            controller: timeController,
          ),
          _TextFieldWidget(
            hintText: 'Episode number',
            controller: episodeNumController,
          ),
          _TextFieldWidget(
            hintText: 'ID',
            controller: idShow,
            id: true,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 68, left: 68),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              //on pressed
              onPressed: () async {
                if (id == null ||
                    courseID == null ||
                    caption == null ||
                    time == null ||
                    link == null ||
                    episodeNum == null) {
                  return;
                }
                await _eps.update(
                  courseIDforEpsUpdate: courseID,
                  id: id,
                  caption: caption,
                  time: time,
                  episodeNum: int.parse(episodeNum),
                  link: link,
                );
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              //text to shoe in to the button
              child: Text(type == ActionType.add ? 'Add' : 'Update',
                  style: const TextStyle(color: AppThemeColors.kDeepBlueTheme)),
              //style section code here
              style: ButtonStyle(
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

please check this too

Comment: share your db image

Comment: @brookyonas please check now

Comment: the code is correct my friend. log this:- id, caption, time and head.

Comment: @brookyonas it's all logging correct...

Comment: Have you checked with this Stackoverflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589274/cloud-firestore-not-updating-correctly-when-record-is-added-in-flutter